# How to distinguish the vscode workspace folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
lgg@DESKTOP-BMR5HSI:~/.vscode-server/data/User/workspaceStorage$ ll
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 8 lgg lgg 4096 Nov 13 21:04 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 lgg lgg 4096 Nov  4 15:45 ../
drwxr-xr-x 3 lgg lgg 4096 Nov 13 21:03 1505181e6052a03abe79042e8bcfdd40/
drwxr-xr-x 2 lgg lgg 4096 Nov 13 21:07 341a5d2d03d5a64ce58dce3771dac3b1/
drwxr-xr-x 3 lgg lgg 4096 Nov 13 21:09 3b9c4219014f64ec29dd383ed3fbbf22/
drwxr-xr-x 3 lgg lgg 4096 Nov 13 21:08 88f5f1b6a49f6f00e103a56adffb3c6e/
drwxr-xr-x 3 lgg lgg 4096 Nov 13 21:04 89f25165af6ff305f0f731e8ef4c6168/
drwxr-xr-x 3 lgg lgg 4096 Nov 13 21:04 ce3c4d069b58e0dbb6f66aa658bc9e93/
```

```
LinGuanguo@DESKTOP-BMR5HSI MINGW64 ~/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/workspaceStorage
$ ll
total 104
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 13 21:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov  9 13:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov  4 19:50 127122aeb91c48b270b04d66d41519fe
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 13 21:03 1505181e6052a03abe79042e8bcfdd40
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 11 22:23 1cf9e5989394bac1441390a899e29a59
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 11 11:04 2f7c21953e4720ec2da7a75cf936ec58
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 13 21:07 341a5d2d03d5a64ce58dce3771dac3b1
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 13 21:11 3b9c4219014f64ec29dd383ed3fbbf22
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov  6 22:46 3e244c4a9f5307bb6e8d698e2018f7f8
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 11 17:29 3f80eb3c628ea4ca4b54afdf25007ab2
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov  4 15:49 5b46f75dd3aeb4d80b002e341ddbafb4
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 11 11:10 5e36229235ec81e2244743a2eb401316
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 13 20:43 6035ef9adf7f887e614eb7a8f51ba89a
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov  4 20:00 7e0ba18ec97371445afce32a443648b6
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 13 21:08 88f5f1b6a49f6f00e103a56adffb3c6e
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 13 21:04 89f25165af6ff305f0f731e8ef4c6168
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov  4 20:10 a3d4c8f6efaf46e48d356d96e70c2bc7
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 13 20:54 b975249a5633acd47927412a74c05e29
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 11 20:43 bbb5565824723bea6acccb7885b4a88f
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov  9 17:52 bbc0500b79cabef3a1039237a7a521c6
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 13 18:36 beb6c5139504366d0a793188f2358174
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 13 21:04 ce3c4d069b58e0dbb6f66aa658bc9e93
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov  8 17:26 d6f908ee23f82eac7a67893b81676e4c
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 13 20:52 ddd1b8bc9902b061f64f1b35fd5b228b
drwxr-xr-x 1 LinGuanguo 197609 0 Nov 12 00:00 fc712a231342bc69c0fef503c95208b8
```

there are a lot of vscode workspace directory in my windows and WSL. How do I distinguish between them and the actual workspace. their name are random.

There are a lot of useful things in them, such as C++'s intellisense cache, but most of them is garbage. I just open a folder once, then vscode save a lot of garbage. I just want to delete them, not rm -r -f *.

The only way I know now is that when I open a workspace, the corresponding folder will appear vscode.lock

```
lgg@DESKTOP-BMR5HSI:~/.vscode-server/data/User/workspaceStorage$ tree
.
├── 1505181e6052a03abe79042e8bcfdd40
│   └── ms-vscode.cpptools
├── 341a5d2d03d5a64ce58dce3771dac3b1
├── 3b9c4219014f64ec29dd383ed3fbbf22
│   ├── ms-vscode.cpptools
│   └── vscode.lock
├── 88f5f1b6a49f6f00e103a56adffb3c6e
│   └── ms-vscode.cpptools
├── 89f25165af6ff305f0f731e8ef4c6168
│   └── ms-vscode.cpptools
└── ce3c4d069b58e0dbb6f66aa658bc9e93
    └── ms-vscode.cpptools
```

Answer (score 1):

Many folders contain a file `workspace.json` with a `folder` property.

Some folders only contain a file `meta.json` that contain the name of one of the workspaces from a Multi Root Workspace. Not very useful because the Multi Root Workspace file already contains these names and locations.

Some folders with a `meta.json` contain a `state.vscdb`.

It looks like the folders with `meta.json` are from a previous version of VSC because they all have dates from years ago (2018/2019).